# Rails scope overriding select

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, optimization, named-scope

I have a model with a has_many relationship, and a scope to determine whether or not it has any children, such as:

```
  scope :with_nomination, :include => [:nomination], :conditions => "nominations.service_id IS NOT NULL"
```

Using this, I can do something like `Service.with_nomination` and receive a list of all services with nomination children.

The problem is that when I do something like `Service.select("id, firstName, lastName").with_nomination` ActiveRecord in essense does a `SELECT * FROM services` which is very bad and does not utilize the indexes I so painstakingly set up.

How can I either rephrase my query or modify my scopes to work with the .select() command?

Comment: I'm no expert at this and will defer to someone else to chime in with a true answer, but I'm thinking you need to do a join or lambda with your scope before you can use select in the manner you wish. I've seen it done before in source I've grok'd on github, but have yet to implement this myself. Just a thought as you wait for a better reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in the syntax I was using, a select is not possible, so it does a select * and any further selects are already overriden.

I re-wrote the scopes like so:

```
scope :no_nomination, joins("LEFT JOIN nominations ON nominations.service_id = services.id").where("nominations.service_id IS NULL")
# important distinction here, the left join allows you to find those records without children

scope :with_nomination, joins(:nomination).where("nominations.service_id IS NOT NULL")
```

Using this syntax allows me to do something like `Service.select(:id,:user,:otherfield).with_nomination`

Answer (score 0):

8 years later...

This is ugly, but you could also convert the resulting `ActiveRecord::Relation` into to sql with `to_sql` and run the command manually with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`.

It might look like this:

```
query = Service.select("id, firstName, lastName").with_nomination.to_sql
records = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
records.first["firstName"] # => First Name
```

This doesn't eliminate the excess columns that the scope retrieves, *and* you have to access each field with string keys, but hey, at least you can still access them!